# What is supposed to be entered after "login as" in PuTTy for SSH?

Tags: ssh, putty

When I open up PuTTy, it says "login as".  What is supposed to be entered?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: You're asking us for your username. Closing as too localized - ask your vendor or support folks.

Answer (score 4):

your username on the remote machine. probably not "root" since the account should be locked for remoteaccess.

---

depending on your linux distribution you set up an account during installation. use that one. otherwise you can add an user from commandline/gui. but again it depends on your linux distribution.

Comment: Okay... any idea how I could find that username with Plesk?

Comment: do you not have credentials for the remote machine?  Usually it isnt root, but depending on how the machine is config'd, you can try it. Most of the time, you should login with non-root and then elevate if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The user name you want to login as... After that it will try and pub/priv key pairs it has (if support), other authentication (like kerberos), then password auth.